# "exited with code 9009" error while trying to build AngularJSToDo Sample app for Visual studio 2013 community

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I downloaded Visual studio 2013 Community today, after that I manually installed all the needed tools for the Apache Cordova extension for visual studio. Then I downloaded the [AngularJS Sample App](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-TODO-Sample-for-b651512a/)
to try it out .. but when I try to build it it gives me that error

> The command "Powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned Unblock-File
>   'C:\Projects\AngularJSTodo Sample for Tools for Apache
>   Cordova\JavaScript\AngularJSToDo\FetchRequirements.ps1'; Powershell
>   -File 'C:\Projects\AngularJSTodo Sample for Tools for Apache Cordova\JavaScript\AngularJSToDo\FetchRequirements.ps1'" exited with
>   code 9009

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The sample projects have been authored in a way that the requisite dependency frameworks will be automatically downloaded when you run the project for the first time.

However, the libraries may fail to download in case the script does not have the right permissions to execute. To fix this:

- Open the folder where you’ve downloaded the sample app
- Identify the FetchRequirements.ps1 file and right click it

[image]

- Choose “Properties”
- Click the Unblock button if it shows up

[image]

Try to run the project again through Visual Studio

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer .. but unfortunately in the file's properties I have no "Unblock" button. what else could I do ?